# Copy remote file to local using ansible - filename is variable

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I'm trying to fetch some files from a remote server, however, the file name is generate by a variable date.

> $(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'%Y-%m')

```
- hosts: remote_server
  tasks:
       fetch:
         src: /tmp/$(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'%Y-%m') 
         dst: /tmp/$(date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" +'%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the `date` command output as an ansible variable and use it in the task

```
- hosts: remote_server
  vars:
    dt: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-15) -1 month" + "%Y-%m"') }}"
  tasks:
    fetch:
      src: "/tmp/{{ dt }}"
      dest: "/tmp/{{ dt }}"
```

Note that the value of `dt` will be dependant on the `date` of the control node.